# How to load Foundation 6 JS in Brunch?

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation, phoenix-framework, brunch

We want to use Foundation 6 JS plugins in our Phoenix/Brunch app, but I can't figure out how to properly hook up Foundation scripts.
As far as I understand they should be loaded after jQuery and will extend it with `.foundation()` function.

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
  "foundation-sites": "^6.2.3",
  "jquery": "^3.1.0",
  "sass-brunch": "^2.6.3",
},
```

**brunch-config.js**

```
exports.config = {
  files: {
    javascripts: {
      joinTo: "js/app.js",
      order: {
        before: [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery",
          "node_modules/foundation-sites/js/foundation.core",
          "node_modules/foundation-sites/js/foundation.topbar"
        ]
       }
    },
    stylesheets: {
      joinTo: "css/app.css"
    },
    templates: {
      joinTo: "js/app.js"
    }
  },

  conventions: {
    assets: /^(web\/static\/assets)/,
    ignored: [
      /\/_.*/
    ]
  },
  paths: {
    watched: [
      "web/static",
      "test/static"
    ],
    public: "priv/static"
  },

  plugins: {
    babel: {
      ignore: [/web\/static\/vendor/, /web\/static\/elm/]
    },
    eslint: {
      pattern: /^web\/static\/js\/.*\.js?$/
    },
    sass: {
      mode: 'native',
      options: {
        includePaths: [
          'node_modules/foundation-sites/scss'
        ]
      }
    }
  },    

  modules: {
    autoRequire: {
      "jquery":            "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery",
      "foundation_core":   "node_modules/foundation-sites/js/foundation.core",
      "foundation_topbar": "node_modules/foundation-sites/js/foundation.topbar",
      "js/app.js":         ["web/static/js/app"]
    }
  },

  npm: {
    enabled: true,
    whitelist: ["phoenix", "phoenix_html", "jquery", "foundation-sites", "scrollreveal"],
    globals: {
      $:      'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
    }
  }
};
```

The Brunch documentation isn't very explicit so I might make a couple of mistakes in that config (when tried to use `autoRequire` and `npm.globals` - what are map keys there?), but nevertheless `$` and `jQuery` global variables are there and pointing to the jQuery library, which is fine.

The problem is that `$(document).foundation` is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

Brunch hasn't compiled assets, cause in the section "modules" you used string values:

```
modules: {
    autoRequire: {
      "jquery":            "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery",
      "foundation_core":   "node_modules/foundation-sites/js/foundation.core",
      "foundation_topbar": "node_modules/foundation-sites/js/foundation.topbar",
      "js/app.js":         ["web/static/js/app"]
    }
},
```

instead you should use an array of strings with paths. So, change it to:

```
modules: {
    autoRequire: {
      "jquery":            ["node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery"],
      "foundation_core":   ["node_modules/foundation-sites/js/foundation.core"],
      "foundation_topbar": ["node_modules/foundation-sites/js/foundation.topbar"],
      "js/app.js":         ["web/static/js/app"]
    }
},
```